# What mushroom inoculation method works better?

Tags: mushrooms, back-to-eden

I've heard about both cardboard, under the plant, and direct seeding inoculation methods for growing wine caps in the soil. Does one method work better than the other? If so which one works better?

Comment: It depends on the mushroom.  I have started shaggy manes by just throwing them onto lawns.

Comment: burying pieces throughout the lawn?

Comment: Just throwing mature ones ( too old to eat) randomly on lawns .